# Building Zapier App - Updating User With Custom Fields

Tags: zapier

I have been building out a Zapier app for my company and all has been going well and I am pretty much finished except for one thing I can't figure out which I am hoping someone can help me with.

Using Zapier Salesforce App as an example that is similar to what I am trying to achieve). Imagine I am trying to update a contact. If I do this is Zapier SFDC app it pulls in all the possible fields on that record which can be completely different due to custom fields.

I am essentially trying to mimic this for updating users in our system but cannot pull in the fields that are available to update for that specific user. I am guessing you use the 'Dynamic Field' feature maybe but I just don't see how it can work which may be down to a lack of something on our end.

Anybody run through this sort of experience before that could offer any inisghts? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you need to implement dynamic custom fields in your app. Here is the documentation: https://zapier.github.io/zapier-platform/#customdynamic-fields

Comment: I never came across this documentation! Thanks! As I feared, it is not something we can do currently so I will have to push our developers to put something in place for this. Thanks!

Comment: it's well described in the documentation but yes it is required development knowledge. You can take help of any professional zapier developer.